# Origin for the song Bederech Hamelech

Tags: sources-mekorot, words, song-poetry, music

Yaakov Shwekey composed a song called *Bederech Hamelech*.

Here are the lyrics:

ומבלעדיך אין לנו מלך 
אין לנו מלך גואל ומושיע
ומבלעדיך אין לנו מלך

אין לנו מלך גואל ומושיע

ומבלעדיך אין לנו מלך
אין לנו מלך גואל ומושיע
ומבלעדיך אין לנו מלך
אין לנו מלך גואל ומושיע

אלא אתה, אלא אתה, אלא אתה אלא אתה, אלא אתה

בדרך המלך, בדרך המלך נלך בדרך המלך נלך לעולם ועד 
בדרך המלך, בדרך המלך נלך בדרך המלך נלך לעולם ועד

Does anyone know where these words come from?

Comment: To be pedantic, it is only sung by Yaakov Shwekey. It was composed by Yitzy Waldner.

Answer (score 2):

Most of the song appears to be from Nishmat (sepharadic Nussach)<sup>(1)</sup> said on Shabbat, while the last line ([בדרך המלך נלך](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%93%D7%A8%D7%9A_%D7%94%D7%9E%D7%9C%D7%9A)) seems to come from Tanach, specifically Bamidbar 21:22:

> "אֶעְבְּרָה בְאַרְצֶךָ, לֹא נִטֶּה בְּשָׂדֶה וּבְכֶרֶם לֹא נִשְׁתֶּה מֵי בְאֵר. **בְּדֶרֶךְ הַמֶּלֶךְ נֵלֵךְ** עַד אֲשֶׁר נַעֲבֹר גְּבֻלֶךָ"

---

<sup>(1)</sup>  <sub>וּמִבַּלְעָדֶיךָ אֵין לָנוּ מֶלֶךְ גּוֹאֵל וּמוֹשִׁיעַ, פּוֹדֶה וּמַצִּיל, וְעוֹנֶה וּמְרַחֵם, בְּכָל עֵת צָרָה וְצוּקָה, אֵין לָנוּ מֶלֶךְ עוֹזֵר וְסוֹמֵךְ אֶלָּא אָתָּה:  ‏</sub>

Comment: Which version of Nishmat did you check? The other answer claims it's entirely from there.

Comment: @DoubleAA I checked the עדות המזרח version and couldn't find that text.

Answer (score 1):

According to the pamphlet that came with the CD, the lyrics are from Nishmas.

[image: From Shwekey's "Maamin B'Nissim/We Are a Miracle" album]

**EDIT:** That said, after actually looking at the various nusachos, it seems that the citation from Nishmas refers only to the first line, and that the line בדרך המלך נלך לעולם ועד was borrowed from Bamidbar 21:22 and went uncited for some reason.